# Flutter Splash Screen Video Player

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

> I am trying to create a background video splash screen for my app. 
>   Currently, I am achieving a blank screen by running this code.

```
 void main() => runApp(WalkThrough());

class WalkThrough extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WalkThroughState createState() => _WalkThroughState();
}

class _WalkThroughState extends State<WalkThrough> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Pointing the video controller to our local asset.
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/video.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Once the video has been loaded we play the video and set looping to true.
        _controller.play();
        _controller.setLooping(true);
        _controller.setVolume(0.0);
        _controller.play();
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
```

> I suspect the problem may be here and have based my research off this [Full screen video background in Flutter on Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075320/full-screen-video-background-in-flutter-on-login) as I am trying to achieve a similar result.

```
          SizedBox.expand(
            child: FittedBox(
              // If your background video doesn't look right, try changing the BoxFit property.
              // BoxFit.fill created the look I was going for.
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _controller.value.size?.width ?? 0,
                height: _controller.value.size?.height ?? 0,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: what is your device?

Comment: @PayamZahedi iPhone 11 Pro

Comment: is it real device or simulator?

Comment: You are also not using MaterialApp widget. did you try after wrapping Scaffold with it?

Comment: @PayamZahedi simulator

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the video player package has an issue to show video in the Ios simulator. I had the same issue and search for it and find out this [issue in Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14647). until now this issue is open. I tested the video player on a real device and there were no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use this video player [video_player plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) 
& Save your mp4 file in assets/videos location
Try the below code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

import 'HomePage.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  bool _visible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/video/splash_video.mp4");
    _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      _controller.setLooping(true);
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
        setState(() {
          _controller.play();
          _visible = true;
        });
      });
    });

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(param_homepage: 'Welcome Home')),
          (e) => false);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    if (_controller != null) {
      _controller.dispose();
      _controller = null;
    }
  }

  _getVideoBackground() {
    return AnimatedOpacity(
      opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
    );
  }

  _getBackgroundColor() {
    return Container(color: Colors.transparent //.withAlpha(120),
        );
  }

  _getContent() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            _getVideoBackground(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```